# Row and column "projection" in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel sheet with *exactly* 1 filled cell per row and column like this:

```
-------------
| 3 |   |   |
-------------
|   |   | 1 |
-------------
|   | 2 |   |
-------------
```

for which I want to create a "projection" row and column like so (the arrows denote the projection direction):

```
-------------       -----
| 3 |   |   |       | 3 |
-------------       -----
|   |   | 1 |  -->  | 1 |
-------------       -----
|   | 2 |   |       | 2 |
-------------       -----
      |
      v
-------------
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
-------------
```

any suggestions of how to accomplish that without resorting to VBA?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! This will be easy with the latest version of Excel.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio could please share some information like what the earliest latest Excel version is that makes it easy and how it is done there (any commands or keywords to search for)? Thanks!

Comment: =SUM(range)   ...

Comment: @jsotola How will the SUM function accomplish what the OP is asking?

Comment: @jsotola does that also work for non-numerical data like text or timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The following functions are only available on Excel365.

Use [TOCOL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed) and [TOROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/torow-function-b90d0964-a7d9-44b7-816b-ffa5c2fe2289) functions to create your "projections" vertically and horizontally.

**TOCOL**

```
=TOCOL(A1:C3;1)
```

[image]

**TOROW**

```
=TOROW(A1:C3;1)
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful answer!